# golang timer re-calculate from zero

Tags: go, timer

I need to write a timer, which may reset itself to zero. For example, I have a

```
trm := time.NewTimer(10)
```

then, if something happened before it has expired, the timer will clear all the data it has, and re-calculate from 0, just like when I re-new a same timer.

I've checked Go's time API, and haven't found anything. Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean that you've checked the go API and found nothing?  If you google "golang timer" the first result is the official standard library docs for golang's time package.  The `Timer` type has only two methods, one of which is `Reset`.  Is that not exactly what you want?

Answer (score 3):

What about to use [`time.Reset`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Reset)?

> Reset changes the timer to expire after duration d. It returns true if
>   the timer had been active, false if the timer had expired or been
>   stopped.

Another solution would be to initialize another timer.

```
t.Reset(x)
t := time.NewTimer(x)
```

are identical, except for avoiding the garbage collection.

A typical example would be the following. It will reset the timer in case the elapsed time is less then the timeout.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    const timeout = 1 * time.Millisecond
    t := time.NewTimer(timeout)
    for {
        t2 := timeout + time.Duration(rand.Intn(100)-50)*timeout/100
        start := time.Now()
        select {
        case <-time.After(t2):
            fmt.Println("Time after:", t2)
        }
        elapsed := time.Since(start)
        if elapsed < timeout {
            fmt.Println("Time ellapsed:", elapsed)
            t.Reset(timeout)
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `timer.Reset` function, to reset the timer. To renew it, pass the same duration, you used initially as parameter. (In your case `10`)

From package documentation:

> Reset changes the timer to expire after duration d. It returns true if the timer had been active, false if the timer had expired or been stopped.

So, when you pass the same duration to `Reset`, timer will start counting from that duration d. And you effectively `renew` the timer.

For example:

```
if eventHappened {
   timer.Reset(10)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure Reset() will start from 0, or continue timing.

Comment: @fding I've updated answer, to address your concern.